# Put two arrays as key and value in Hashtable

Tags: android, hashtable

I am quite new to Android..Can someone please help me to solve this problem ?

I have a `Hashtable` and two `Arrays`. I have to put these two `Arrays` as key and pair values in the `Hashtable`.

```
String[] arr = data.split(",");

    String keyarr = arr[0].toString();
    String[] keystring = keyarr.split("-");
    System.out.println("get the string arrayy " + string[0] + string[1]);
    String valuearr = arr[1].toString();
    String[] valuestring = valuearr.split("-");
    Hashtable<String, String> hashtable = new Hashtable<String, String>();
```

Here `keystring` and `valuestring` are two arrays, and I would like to put those in the hashtable. If `keyString[0]` is the key then `valuesting[0]` is the value of that hashtable. Thanks..

Comment: Your `Hashtable` declaration isn't correct it should be `Hashtable<String, String>`. Please read about [Hashtable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) in the docs and ask a specific question instead of asking for code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to below written code,It would solve your issue.

> If keyString[0] is the key then valuesting[0] is the value of that hashtable.

Instead of adding whole array as key, add element of key-array as key and get the corresponding value from value-array.

```
    Hashtable<String, String> ht = new Hashtable<>();
    String[] keys = {"key1", "key2"};
    String[] values = {"value1", "value2"};
    for(int i =0 ;i<keys.length;i++){
        ht.put(keys[i], values[i]);
    }
```